# What version of julia is compatible with glibc 2.12?

Tags: julia, centos6, glibc, mat

I am currently running CentOS 6 and I need to run the MAT package on julia. I noticed that glibc version 2.12 is not supported with julia 0.6. Is the lower version of julia compatible with glibc version 2.12?

Comment: I suggest to ask the folks who provide the [julia COPR repository](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/nalimilan/julia/) why they stopped building for EPEL 6. Maybe it's just an oversight.